# VB.Net Comparison Error Between Integer Variable and Integer

Tags: vb.net

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim name As String
        Dim age As Integer
        Dim range As String

        Console.WriteLine("What's your name?")
        name = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}, how old are you?")
        age = Console.ReadLine()

        If 0 <= age < 1 Then
            range = " child."
        ElseIf 1 <= age < 2 Then
            range = " toddler."
        ElseIf 2 <= age < 12 Then
            range = " child."
        ElseIf 12 <= age < 19 Then
            range = " teenager."
        ElseIf 19 <= age < 64 Then
            range = "n adult."
        Else
            range = " pensioner."
        End If
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}, you are a{range}")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

When I input age as 10, range is still " child.", even though it isn't in the range of 0 <= age < 1. However, when I change them from `x <= age < y` into `age >= x And age < y`, it works.
Does Visual Basic not allow comparison like this? I know Python allows it.

Answer (score 3):

.net logic expressions can't really be expressed like that, the second part of your condition will actually be getting evaluated to a logic expression.  Eg, is age < than 1 and is the result of that expression greater or equal than the left  value.

However, you can reverse the logic and simplify your expression tree by starting at the top and working your way down.  Something like this.

```
If age >= 65 Then
    range = "pensioner"
ElseIf age >= 19 Then
    range = "adult"
ElseIf age >= 12 Then
    range = "teenager"
ElseIf age >= 2 Then
    range = "Child"
ElseIf age >= 1 Then
    range = "toddler"
Else
    range = "child"
End If
```

Or if you want to keep it in the same flow, you will need to join the two conditions using AndAlso.  Eg:

```
If 0 <= age AndAlso age < 1 Then
```